# How to show only yesterday's sales with previous inventory stocks

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a Table View like below.

How can we show the sales of yesterday (marked as S in DATATYPE) but need to show all other DATATYPE marked as 'I'?

The required output is shown on the last t

```html
+----------+-----------+-----------------+
| DATATYPE | SALESDATE | SERIALNO        |
+----------+-----------+-----------------+
| I        | 20160730  | 355274073159321 |
+----------+-----------+-----------------+
| I        | 20160730  | 355274073158927 |
+----------+-----------+-----------------+
| I        | 20160730  | 355274073166888 |
+----------+-----------+-----------------+
| I        | 20160730  | 355274073157333 |
+----------+-----------+-----------------+
| I        | 20160730  | 355274073158851 |
+----------+-----------+-----------------+
| I        | 20160730  | 355274073159784 |
+----------+-----------+-----------------+
| I        | 20160730  | 355274073158828 |
+----------+-----------+-----------------+
| I        | 20160730  | 355274073158950 |
+----------+-----------+-----------------+
| I        | 20160730  | 355274073157960 |
+----------+-----------+-----------------+
| S        | 20160731  | 355274073159230 |
+----------+-----------+-----------------+
| S        | 20160730  | 355274073166904 |
+----------+-----------+-----------------+
| S        | 20160730  | 355274073190128 |
+----------+-----------+-----------------+
| S        | 20160730  | 355274073158679 |
+----------+-----------+-----------------+
| S        | 20160730  | 355274073159255 |
+----------+-----------+-----------------+
| S        | 20160730  | 355274073159925 |
+----------+-----------+-----------------+

I need the output like this. Only show yesterday sale (say today is 01-Aug-2016) and all item marked as I on DATATYPE column

+----------+-----------+-----------------+
| DATATYPE | SALESDATE | SERIALNO        |
+----------+-----------+-----------------+
| I        | 20160730  | 355274073159321 |
+----------+-----------+-----------------+
| I        | 20160730  | 355274073158927 |
+----------+-----------+-----------------+
| I        | 20160730  | 355274073166888 |
+----------+-----------+-----------------+
| I        | 20160730  | 355274073157333 |
+----------+-----------+-----------------+
| I        | 20160730  | 355274073158851 |
+----------+-----------+-----------------+
| I        | 20160730  | 355274073159784 |
+----------+-----------+-----------------+
| I        | 20160730  | 355274073158828 |
+----------+-----------+-----------------+
| I        | 20160730  | 355274073158950 |
+----------+-----------+-----------------+
| I        | 20160730  | 355274073157960 |
+----------+-----------+-----------------+
| S        | 20160731  | 355274073159230 |
+----------+-----------+-----------------+
```

My full select is

```
SELECT     bi.btLatinAbbrev, 'C710' AS SUBS, CASE WHEN bi.btLatinAbbrev = 'Sales' THEN 'S' ELSE 'I' END AS DATATYPE, REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(10), bi.buDate, 112), '/', '') AS SALESDATE, 
                      'C000079967' AS FROMSITE, CASE WHEN snc.Qty = 1 THEN '' ELSE 'EU' END AS TOSITE, snc.SN AS SERIALNO
FROM         dbo.vwExtended_bi AS bi INNER JOIN
                      dbo.snt000 AS snt ON snt.biGUID = bi.biGUID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.snc000 AS snc ON snc.GUID = snt.ParentGUID
WHERE     (bi.btLatinAbbrev = 'Sales') OR
                      (snc.Qty = 1)
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, edit your question with more explanation and expected output.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: You are storing dates in a text column?  This is a good habit to kick.  Always use the correct [data type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx).  It makes solving problems like this much easier.  It also reduces the chance of your system holding an incorrect value.

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT DATATYPE,CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),SALESDATE,112) SALESDATE,SERIALNO FROM table
WHERE
    ( DATATYPE = 'S' AND
      SALESDATE =  convert(date,GETDATE()-1)
    ) OR 
    DATATYPE = 'I'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using [CONVERT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT DATATYPE, SALESDATE, SERIALNO FROM TABLE WHERE
    SALESDATE = CONVERT(NVARCHAR,GETDATE()-1,112)
    AND DATATYPE = 'S'  --sales yesterday
UNION ALL    
SELECT DATATYPE, SALESDATE, SERIALNO FROM TABLE WHERE
    CONVERT(DATETIME,SALESDATE,112) <= CONVERT(DATETIME,GETDATE()-1,112)
    AND DATATYPE = 'I'  --I yesterday to back
  ) AS T
ORDER BY T.DATATYPE DESC, CONVERT(DATETIME,T.SALESDATE,112) DESC, T.SERIALNO DESC
```

supponsing SERIALNO as numeric

Comment: I need to shows only yesterday's sales and columns marked as 'I' (from yesterday to back)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM Tbl
WHERE
    ( DATATYPE = 'S' AND
      SALESDATE = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(11), GETDATE() - 1, 112) -- 20160731 
    ) OR 
    DATATYPE = 'I'
```